# Sed \w character class not working with replace on mac

Tags: regex, macos, sed

When I execute this command on OSX, I would expect each letter to be replaced by an "x", but none of the letters are replaced:

```
$ echo 'a b c' | sed 's/\w/x/g'
```

output: `a b c`

This works just fine:

```
echo 'a b c' | sed 's/[[:alpha:]]/x/g'
```

output: `x x x`

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think `sed` supports `\w`. (it's not perl, after all) . Maybe with `sed -r ...` invocation. Check `man sed`. Not really a programming Q, in the future post such issues on [unix.se] . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that the BSD implementation of sed on Mac is different from other linux machines

You can install gnu sed. Run the following command on Apple Mac OS:

```
$ brew install gnu-sed
```

reference: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-text-in-files-in-linux-unix-shell/

Comment: and use as `gsed`